# How to write elseif into linear programming

Tags: linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

Given:

```
If a < 0 and c < 0:
  d = 1
else:
 d = 0
```

I was wondering how to write it into statement of linear statement?

Comment: What do you mean by a statement "of linear statement"?

Comment: Something like the links  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2989788/if-else-statement-in-linear-programming-with-same-variable

Comment: it should be "statement in linear programming ", I cannot edit my question. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write if-else statement in linear programming representation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4318236/write-if-else-statement-in-linear-programming-representation)

Comment: @RobPratt Yes, it is almost. I am thankful your help.

Comment: Just replace $a$ and $c$ with their negatives, and replace $d$ with $c$.